# asp.net ajax collapsible panel in ie8 problem

Tags: asp.net, internet-explorer-8, collapsiblepanelextender

Anyone try this simple bit of code in an ie8 browswer and try refreshing the page,

in ie8 you will get an error around getelementbyid on refresh.

When i run it it complains of not being able to find control with id of 'ctl00_main_dd'

```
<cc1:CollapsiblePanelExtender ID="CollapsiblePanelExtender2" runat="server"     
     ImageControlID="Image2" CollapsedImage="~/App_Themes/IMStandard/icons/uparrow.png"
    ExpandedImage="~/App_Themes/IMStandard/icons/downarrow.png"
     CollapseControlID="dd" ExpandControlID="dd"
     TargetControlID="pnlQuickKeywordSearch"
     SuppressPostBack="true">
</cc1:CollapsiblePanelExtender>
 <asp:Panel ID="dd" runat="server">
    <h3 class="loginHeader">
        <asp:Image ID="Image2" runat="server" />
        &nbsp;&nbsp;Quick Keyword search&nbsp;<asp:Image ID="HelpIconImage" runat="server"
            Width="16px" Height="16px" ImageUrl="~/App_Themes/IMStandard/icons/help.png" /></h3>
</asp:Panel>
 <asp:Panel ID="pnlQuickKeywordSearch" Style="float: left; border: double 3px #C9DF86;"
    runat="server" >
    <div style="clear: both; padding: 5px;">
    </div></asp:Panel>
```

Anybody know why this is happening? is it a bug in ie8 or am i missing something?

By the way, i am using masterpages, but i dont think that has anything to do with it.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This example works for me in my IE8 running on Windows 7.
The id 'ctl00_main_dd' is typically the generated clientside ID (VS2010 will enable us to specify client side ID's.)

Can you use a div instead of the asp:panel for your expand/collapse control ?

```
<div ID="dd">
    <h3 class="loginHeader">
        <asp:Image ID="Image2" runat="server" />
          Quick Keyword search <asp:Image ID="HelpIconImage" runat="server"
            Width="16px" Height="16px" ImageUrl="~/App_Themes/IMStandard/icons/help.png" /></h3>
</div>
```

The collapsible panel extender should then be able to find the static 'dd' client ID.

Added 02.06:
No good guesses to why it happens in IE8 only

I would check =>

1) Correct doctype in masterpage

```
DOCTYPE html PUBLIC “-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN” “http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd”
```

2) Tick the compatibility view button in IE8 if present

3) Ensure all VS, Framework and Toolkit are latest versions (SP1)

Comment: it didnt work, any have any ideas on this? it shouldnt be happening?

Comment: Are you using the latest version of the toolkit ? Update VS / framwork / toolkit with VS versions if you havent done so already. Besides that, I'm all out of ideas

Answer (score 0):

We just had a weird scenario where there was a  tag inside the collapsed panel with style="float:right;", and removing div tag fixed the issue.  Hopefully that helps someone else.